# Highlight HTML code when clicking element in browser while live previewing

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, adobe-brackets, codekit

Adobe Brackets has one good built-in feature: While live previewing an HTML doc, you can click any element in the browser and Brackets will highlight the specific code.

I'm looking for other text editors, browser plugins, or apps that can do this?

Visual Studio Code is currently my editor of choice, but haven't yet found a plugin that can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use bootstrap studio as a text editor.
You can even change elements in the editor itself

https://bootstrapstudio.io/

you can use the webdemo, if you really like it you can use your student license for a free year or buy it.
Hope this will help you
have a good day :)